# The only person who/that can read

Tags: pronouns

The only person **who/that** can read and write English well is my friend.

In this sentence why **that** is preferred?

Comment: [Is . . . "that" preferred?](http://i.stack.imgur.com/jmkVX.jpg)

Comment: I believe it's to do with how the sentence is constructed. In your example, the emphasis is on an ability of your friend and _that_ is appropriate.  Change the wording, however: _My friend is the only person who can read and write English well._ The emphasis is now about your friend.

Answer (score 1):

Who and that are also used as relative pronouns.  In the defining relative clause, as in the sentence presented by the OP, you can use either who or that as a relative pronoun, but "that" is more informal; it's not a matter of preference.